# How to use complex SQL scripts with python

Tags: python, sql

I could write a SP inside Mysql and excute with a call statement. But looking to write it in python instead.  I got stuck with using sql script on multiple lines.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MySQL;PWD=xxxx') 
csr = conn.cursor()

Sql= 'SELECT something, something 
    FROM table 
    WHERE foo=bar 
    ORDER BY foo '

csr.execute(Sql)
sqld = csr.fetchall()
```

Comment: Put the text in triple quotes - that way it doesn't give you a syntax error because of the linebreaks.

Comment: @Shadikka: Please post your answer as an answer, not a comment.  We can't give you credit if it's only a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh, I don't mind to make it a proper answer.

String literals in triple quotes can include linebreaks and won't cause syntax errors. Otherwise (with "string" or 'string') you will need to include a backslash before every linebreak to make it work. And from experience, that's easy to screw up. :)

As a minor note, in Python variables are usually started with a lowercase letter, names starting with capital letters usually being given to classes.

So:

```
Sql = """SELECT something, something 
         FROM table 
         WHERE foo=bar 
         ORDER BY foo"""
```

Comment: Any idea how to do """Truncate table2; Select * from table1;""". Using double ; within a csr.execute(Sql)...causes a prob

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the overhead, take a look at [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/):

> SQLAlchemy is the Python SQL toolkit and Object Relational Mapper that gives application developers the full power and flexibility of SQL.