# MySQL - Match two tables contains HUGE DATA and find the similar data

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my SQL.
Table 1 contains many data, but Table 2 contains huge data.

Here's the code I implement using Python

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd="", db="fak")
cursor = db.cursor()

#Execute SQL Statement:
cursor.execute("SELECT invention_title FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE invention_title IN (SELECT invention_title FROM us_pat_2005_to_2012)")

#Get the result set as a tuple:
result = cursor.fetchall()

#Iterate through results and print:
for record in result:
    print record
print "Finish."

#Finish dealing with the database and close it
db.commit()
db.close()
```

However, it takes so long. I have run the Python script for 1 hour, and it still doesn't give me any results yet.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have index on invention_title in both tables? If not, then create it:

```
ALTER TABLE auip_wipo_sample ADD KEY (`invention_title`);
ALTER TABLE us_pat_2005_to_2012 ADD KEY (`invention_title`);
```

Then combine your query into one which don't use subqueries:

```
SELECT invention_title FROM auip_wipo_sample 
INNER JOIN us_pat_2005_to_2012 ON auip_wipo_sample.invention_title = us_pat_2005_to_2012.invention_title
```

And let me know about your results.

Comment: It says something like this `ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''invention_title')' at line 1")`

Comment: Anyway I am now adding the index directly from PHPMyAdmin, and I think it's still processing.

Comment: @EdwardOctavianusPakpahan My query is correct. I guess you made a mistake when putting it on your code. Maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797222/how-to-use-complex-sql-scripts-with-python